# Work with date in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, aggregation

I have DataFrame like below:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2020-12-01', periods=5, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : ["1", "2", "1", "1", "2"],
                   "Date" : rng,
                   "status" : ["B2", "G8", "G8", "R7", "G8"]})
```

And I need to create DataFrame where will be:

1. New1 = date of the last agreement with B2 status
2. New2 = date of the last agreement with G8 status

Below I upload result which I need:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First idea is filter only rows with `status` by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and then use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with `last` aggregate function:

```
df = (df[df['status'].isin(['B2','G8'])]
        .pivot_table(index='ID', columns='status', values='Date', aggfunc='last')
        .rename(columns={'B2':'New1','G8':'New2'})
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        )

print (df)
  ID       New1       New2
0  1 2020-12-01 2020-12-03
1  2        NaT 2020-12-05
```

Or you can replace non match rows by `status` to `NaT` in `Date`:

```
df = (df.assign(Date = df['Date'].where(df['status'].isin(['B2','G8'])))
        .pivot_table(index='ID', columns='status', values='Date', aggfunc='last')
        .rename(columns={'B2':'New1','G8':'New2'})
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        )
```